# How to get Display Name Attribute using PropertyDescriptor C# ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using property descriptor to generically iterate over the properties and print their attribute names as table header. It works fine printing the property name, but not for the [Display(Name = "Test")]

Class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    public string DELETE { get; set; }
    public string PARTNO { get; set; } //Part Number
```

Markup:

```
    @foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Model[0]))
    {
       <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this)" class="tableSortHeaderBtnStyle">@descriptor.DisplayName;</th>
    }
```

Just prints the "DELETE" name rather than "Test".  The descriptor has a Name, and DisplayName option and both are set to "DELETE"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there descriptor.Identifier.Text property on your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `[DisplayName("Test")]` instead of `[Display(Name = "Test")]`, please check this:

```
public class Transaction
{
    //[Display(Name = "Test")]
    [DisplayName("Test")]
    public string DELETE { get; set; }
    public string PARTNO { get; set; } //Part Number 
}
```

You can check this in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9aBhr).

Comment: Thank you that worked. The other one is part of DataAnnotations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[DisplayName("Test")]` in place of `[Display(Name = "Test")]`